# What to do with links / imagery with sexual content?

Tags: discussion, moderation, hyperlinks

I came across [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/7451/77195) where the first URL links to a pornographic site (In the meantime I have edited out the links in the answer). While these links were (probably) posted in good faith and the answer has been upvoted a few times this raised a few questions for me:

- Is it appropriate to link to pornographic sites such as the one mentioned above?
- Is it appropriate to link to sites that contain sexual content, but is not the main focus / is locked away behind age confirmation? For example [Newgrounds](http://newgrounds.com)?
- Is it appropriate to post imagery of sexual content if the question could call for it? For example would it be reasonable that [Age Rating: female nipples poking through clothing?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/152637/77195) contains images of female nipples poking through clothing?

Answer (score 4):

**Is it appropriate to post imagery of sexual content if the question could call for it?**

No, it is even less appropriate than posting links since everyone that sees the question / answer will instantly be greeted with imagery that may or may not be offensive to them. Such images should be completely removed and any question that relies on them should be re-worded to not need the image.

Comment: Why did you split this answer up like this? You're not providing different viewpoints; you're answering a three-part question. I'd advise you to put all three of your answers into one answer.

Comment: @ArwenEvenstar because people might have different opinions on all three parts of the question (one of my answers has +1, one has -1, perfect example haha). This way you can vote on the specific part of the question that you agree / disagree with. This would be difficult if all three were combined into one. If people agree this should be one answer I will combine them all into one :)

Answer (score 3):

**Is it appropriate to link to pornographic sites such as the one mentioned above?**

Yes. It is appropriate to post links to pornographic sites as long as they are relevant **and they are clearly advertised as having sexual content** (such as the answer linked in the question). Clicking links are voluntary and they do not hurt or offend anyone that decides not to click on them.

Comment: Might be worth differentiating the levels of the link add some description: erotic poses, simple nudity, or in full action. I'm personally fine with anything if there's a warning on the link.

Comment: I'd want to investigate whether we have any particular legal duty beyond this in certain more puritanical jurisdictions. but to me this seems like the option most in keeping with the StackExchange spirit. We're a site for expert advice. If a particular link helps support that, I think we can trust our users to be responsible and not water it down for them. As long as it's noted up-front and not sprung on someone who wasn't expecting content like that (eg. if they're searching for help at their office/studio)

Answer (score 0):

**Is it appropriate to link to sites that contain sexual content, but is not the main focus / is locked away behind age confirmation?**

Yes, but **only** if the content is hidden as in not present or directly accessible from the linked page. Even better if it's behind a barrier such as log-in or other age confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solutions are best in my opinion and I think that all pornographic or NSFW imagery or content should be hidden behind a link with a proper warning. Other than that, there should be no restrictions to content that can be linked here if the content is relevant to the post.

Ex: 
I should be able to [link nude imagery](http://ThisIsSomeBadExampleForPornographicContentLinkingInMyOpinion) as an example to a post asking about nudity in games but I shouldn't be able to embed the said imagery in the post itself and expose everyone to the image even if they didn't want to see it. ([NSFW](http://ThisIsSomeGoodExampleForPornographicContentLinkingInMyOpinion))

Answer (score -2):

**Is it appropriate to link to pornographic sites such as the one mentioned above**

No. It is not appropriate and should be removed when encountered and - if possible - replaced with a general statement without giving specific examples (e.g. "*But, you can publish your application on alternative markets allowing pornographic content*").